# Command Line Alphabetical Order?

Tags: c++, command-line

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

if(argv[0] < argv[1])
        cout << "IN ORDER";
else
cout << 'NOT IN ORDER";

return 0;
}
```

Cant find out how.

What are Command Line arguments ? and how do i use them ?
I have to write a program  that prints on prints is "IN ORDER" if the command-line arguments  are in alphabetical ascending order; if not print "NOT IN ORDER" if these arguments  are out of order.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I've tried to many ways to do it, but cant find out how to use command line arguments.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that argv[0] is the name of the executable, not what humans would think of as the first command line argument.

Comment: ok so i find if the names of the executables are ascending in characters or what ?

Comment: Stop using caps in your question. Caps mean you are shouting, and people don't like to help people who shout at them.

Comment: @IshakM When you run your program, you typically type something like `$ ./myFile` into the terminal.  You can supply *arguments* by writing `$ ./myFile myArg1 myArg2`. (I suggest you use an `@` notification if you want replies, since I only saw this by backing up in my browser.)

Comment: Im using a turingscraft codelab online compiler. sorry i wasnt specific

Comment: `argv[0] < argv[1]` is simply comparing pointers by the memory address they point to. Look at `strcmp()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line arguments start with index 1 because index 0 is the name of the executable itself.  Are you needing to be case sensitive in the comparison?  If not, you can do something simple like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int index;
    /*for( index = 1; index < argc; ++index )
     * printf( "argv[%d] = %s\n", index, argv[index] );
     */
    for( index = 1; index < argc - 1; ++index )
        if( strcmp( argv[index], argv[index + 1] ) > 0 )
            break;
    int in_order_flag = ( index == argc - 1 );
    printf( in_order_flag ? "IN ORDER\n" : "NOT IN ORDER\n" );
    return 0;
}
```